# Incidence matrix to locate specific information in a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to build an incidence matrix in r that will allow me to check for incidences of the information in a selected row of a dataframe.

If my data looks like this:

```
    A   B   C
01  Cat Hat Car
02  Cat Coat Bike
03  Dog Hat Motorcycle
04  Dog Coat Car
```

I'd like to create a table using a target row (row A in this example) to generate a table like this:

```
    Cat Hat Car
02  1   0   0
03  0   1   0
04  0   0   1
```

Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your row 1 as your dataframe titles and [ifelse] to find text and replace with numerics.

```
# Create object for dataframe.
cat <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Dog")
hat <- c("Coat", "Hat", "Coat")
car <- c("Bike", "Motorcycle", "Car")
# Create dataframe.
df1 <- data.frame(cat, hat, car)

# Create df2 to add the digit replacements,
# keeping df1 for later comparison.
df2 <- df1

# Use [ifelse] to find text and replace with numerics.
df2$cat <- ifelse(df1$cat == "Cat",1 ,0 )
df2$hat <- ifelse(df1$hat == "Hat",1 ,0 )
df2$car <- ifelse(df1$car == "Car",1 ,0 )
```

Comment: This worked for me - I think the issue I was having with Sotos' solution is that my actual data involves email addresses, IPs etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to extract the first row as a vector and not as a data frame. A simple comparison will then do the job, i.e.

```
df[-1,] == as.character(as.vector(df[1,]))
#       A     B     C
#02  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#03 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#04 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Convert to 0/1 by simply multiplying with 1 (a bit of code golf)

```
(df[-1,] == as.character(as.vector(df[1,])))*1
#   A B C
#02 1 0 0
#03 0 1 0
#04 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Sotos is much more elegant, but you can also do something like this with `tidyverse`:

```
df[-1, ] %>%
 rename_at(1:3, funs(paste0(as.character(df[1,])))) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 mutate(val = ifelse(val == var, 1, 0)) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  Car Cat Hat
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1
3   1   0   0
```

Or:

```
df %>% 
 setNames(as.character(df[1,])) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 mutate(val = ifelse(val == var, 1, 0)) %>%
 spread(var, val) %>%
 filter(rowid != 1) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  Car Cat Hat
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1
3   1   0   0
```

First, it sets the column names with the values from the first row. Second, it transforms the data from wide to long. Finally, it compares whether the value is the same as the column name and then applies the given condition.